# upload_err_partial error when uploading files of size greater than 3GB

Tags: php, file-upload, large-files

I want to upload upto 10GB files using a normal php form. But even after increasing the below values,

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
php_value upload_max_filesize
php_value post_max_size
request_terminate_timeout
FcgidMaxRequestLen
```

am able to upload a file upto 3.5gb without any problem. But above that am getting an error as "upload_err_partial". I also reffered a lot of site but the answer I thought releavant was adding `"header(connection:close)"`. I added the line but still I did not get any result. Could anyone guide me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually means that the uploading is cancelled by the user , and some times it can be server problem also which can cause this. Try to contact to your hosting provider and see what can he do

Comment: Hi Hudixt, Thank you for your response. without the user interruption am getting the error. Is that this is reallay a problem to be dealt with the hosting provider or I can try any possibility in the code itself.

Comment: You have to dealt with the hosting provider